# Template function specialization based on static member type

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I don't have a lot of experience with templates but I am wondering if the following scenario is possible. Assume we have a class S with static member stat. I can get it to dynamically generate different code using typeid as:

```
    template <class S>
    void foo() 
    { 
        if (typeid(S::stat) == typeid(AType))
            implementation 1;
        else
            implementation 2;
    }
```

But since all information is known at compile time is it possible to create a specialization of foo for S::stat being of type Atype?

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking to do something like this:

```
template<typename T> class foo_impl {

public:

    static void foo()
    {
          // This is your implementation 2
    }
};

template<> class foo_impl<AType> {

public:

    static void foo()
    {
          // This is your implementation 1
    }
};

template <class S>
    void foo() 
    {
        foo_impl<typename S::Stat>::foo();
    }
```

Comment: foo_impl<typename S::stat>::foo();

This generated the following error with visual studio:
error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before 'MyClass::_stat64'

MyClass::stat is a static const variable. Can it be references as typename S::stat?

Comment: @KostasKyriakopoulos You need to pick a different name than "stat", for your variable. That name conflicts with the stat() system call from the C library.

Answer (score 0):

One common way of solving this problem is through tag dispatching. We can, at compile time, produce different *types* for whether or not `S::stat` matches `AType` - and use those types to call different overloads:

```
template <class S>
void foo() {
    foo_impl(std::is_same<decltype(S::stat), AType>{});
}

void foo_impl(std::true_type /* S::stat matches AType */) {
    // implementation 1
}

void foo_impl(std::false_type /* S::stat doesn't match AType */) {
    // implementation 2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to utilize the decltype solution because my compiler does not support it.

I was able to utilize the foo_impl class solution but only when I declare MyClass as:

`class MyClass {
    public:
        typedef AType Stat;
        static const Stat stat = VAL;
    ...
    }`